# How do I call a service from inside a SQLiteOpenHelper class?

Tags: java, android, intentservice

In Android I need to start a service imediatlly after a database query so I can request missing bytes from an App. I'm calling it like this:

```
Intent service = new Intent("br.com.company.intent.DO_CHUNK_REQUEST");
service.putExtra("FIELD_NAME", fieldName);
service.putExtra("JOB_NAME", jobName);
service.putExtra("START_BYTE", 500);
service.putExtra("LENGTH", 100);
AWS myCall = new AWS();
myCall.chama_servico(service);
```

and I created a another class to work as a "service caller", since I can't extend my class to SQLiteOpenHelper and Service at the same time. My class is like this:

```
package br.com.company.AWService;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class AWS extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void chama_servico (Intent service) {
        startService(service);
    }
}
```

But when I run this code I get an NullPointerException at startService(service). What Am I doing wrong? Is there a better/correct way to call a service after a database query?

Thanks!

Comment: "Is there a better/correct way to call a service after a database query?" -- have whoever does the query invoke the service.

Comment: Problem is that the query can result in multiple calls to the service. I'd have to store all the missing bytes in a list or hashMap.

Comment: That is not an issue In service there is method named onStartCommand() which will always be called when you start service and if you want to avoid this as well you can control that by taking a FLAG to know is service is already running.

Answer (score 0):

We Never creates object of a service in the code.. You must revisit Service concept..

```
AWS myCall = new AWS();// Bad Practice
```

And if its business requirement yes we can do it and make sure to run service code in separate thread as  by default service runes in the same thread from where it is been called.